# User defined output redirection not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I am using a `KSH` script to execute a binary (program) that has the following syntax to execute correctly:

- `myprog [-v | --verbose (optional)] [input1] [input2]`

The program prints nothing & returns exit code 0 (zero) on success. On failure it prints ERROR messages to `STDERR` & returns `exit status > 0`. If `-v` option is specified it prints verbose details to `STDOUT` both in case of success and failure.

To make this usable and reduce chances of argument swapping and user controlled logging I used a ksh shell script to invoke this binary. The syntax to run the ksh shell script is as:

- myshell.sh [-v (optional)] [-a input1] [-b input2]

If `-v` option is specified, ksh redirects `STDOUT` to `<execution_date_time>_out.log` and `STDERR` to `<execution_date_time>_err.log`. My ksh script is as follows:

myshell.sh :

```
#! /bun/ksh

verbopt=""
log=""
arg1=""
arg2=""
dateTime=`date +%y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`

while getopts "va:b:" arg
do
    case $arg in

        v) # verbose output
            verbopt="-v"
            log="1>${dateTime}_out.log 2>${dateTime}_err.log"
            ;;
        a) # Input 1
            arg1=$OPTARG
            ;;
        b) # Input 2
            arg2=$OPTARG
            ;;
        *) # usage
            echo "USAGE: myshell.sh [-v] [-a input1] [-b input2]"
           exit 2
            ;;
    esac
done

if [[ -z $arg1|| -z $arg2]]
then
    echo "Missing arguments"
    exit 2
fi

myprog $verbopt $arg1 $arg2 $log
exit $?
```

The problem here is, all the output `STDERR` & `STDOUT` is printed on the screen (i.e, No redirection took place) as well as no `*.log` files were created after successful or unsuccessful execution (i.e, exit status: 0 or >0 respectively).

Can anyone help me out on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to monkey patch redirections into the command line, just redirect the streams when you parse the flags.  That is:

```
while getopts "va:b:" arg
do
    case $arg in

        v) # verbose output
            verbopt="-v"
            exec 1>${dateTime}_out.log 2>${dateTime}_err.log
            ;;
...
```

You need to be a little careful, since you do some error checking after this and you probably don't want your later error messages going to the *_err.log, but that's fairly trivial to fix.  (eg, error check sooner, or do a `test -n "$verbopt" && exec > ...` after the error check, or similar)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `>` is not expanded in the value of `$log`.

I'm afraid you will need to use a conditional for this, for example:

```
cmd="myprog $verbopt $arg1 $arg2"

if [ "$log" ]; then
    $cmd 1>${dateTime}_out.log 2>${dateTime}_err.log
else
    $cmd
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the idiom `exec` *redirection*, which runs the rest of the script as if the given redirection had been supplied when it was run:

```
if need_to_log; then
  exec >stdout_file 2>stderr_file
fi
this command will be logged if the above if statement was true
```

If you need to restore stdout and stderr afterward for the script to do more unlogged things, you can just run the logging part in a subshell:

```
(
  if need_to_log; then
    exec >stdout_file 2>stderr_file
  fi
  this command will be logged if the above if statement was true
)
this command will not be logged regardless
```

I would also build the command in an array, so you can add things like `-v` to it without having to have a separate variable for each possible parameter. If the order in which the `-a` and `-b` arguments are supplied to `myprog` doesn't matter, you can just add those to the array instead of having separate variables as well.

You can see my version below. Besides the above changes, I also don't bother getting the timestamp if not logging, since it's unneeded, and send error messages to standard error instead of standard out using the ksh builtin `print`.

Here's what I put together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

# new array syntax requires ksh93+; for older ksh, use this:
# set -A cmd myprog
cmd=(myprog) # build up the command to run in an array
log_flag=0   # nonzero if the command should be logged
input_a=     # the two input filenames
input_b=

while getopts 'va:b:' arg; do
  case $arg in
    v) # verbose output
       # older ksh: set -A cmd "${cmd[@]}" -v
       cmd+=(-v)
       log_flag=1
       ;;
    a) # Input 1
       input_a=$OPTARG
       ;;
    b) # Input 2
       input_b=$OPTARG
       ;;
    *) # usage
       print -u2 "USAGE: $0 [-v] [-a input1] [-b input2]"
       exit 2
       ;;
  esac
done

if [[ -z $input_a || -z $input_b ]]; then
  print -u2 "$0: Missing arguments"
  exit 2
fi

if (( log_flag )); then
  timestamp=$(date +%y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)
  exec  >"${timestamp}_out.log" 2>"${timestamp}_err.log"
fi

"${cmd[@]}" "$input_a" "$input_b"
```

Your timestamp uses the two-digit year (`%y`); that and the underscore between the components  are the only deviations from the ISO 8601 standard, so I would recommend you go ahead and adopt the standard format. That'd be `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`, or, in C libraries with newer versions of `strftime`, `%FT%T`.

You could also be a little more clever and make `log_flag` a string that is either empty or `-q`, pass that to the command, and test it against the empty string to determine whether or not to open the log files, but I find the logic easier to follow with the simple 0/1 value treated as a Boolean.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the `eval` command.

Replace ...

```
myprog $verbopt $arg1 $arg2 $log
```

with:

```
eval myprog $verbopt $arg1 $arg2 $log
```

---

I don't know what your `myprog` does but here's a simple example using `eval` to run `date` (valid command) and `date xyz` (invalid command), redirecting output to log.stdout/log.stderr accordingly:

```
$ cat logout
log='1>log.stdout 2>log.stderr'

'rm' -rf log.std* > /dev/null 2>&1

echo ""
echo 'eval date ${log}'
eval date ${log}

echo ""
echo "++++++++++++ log.stdout"
cat log.stdout
echo "++++++++++++ log.stderr"
cat log.stderr
echo "++++++++++++"

'rm' -rf log.std* > /dev/null 2>&1

echo ""
echo 'eval date xyz ${log}'
eval date xyz ${log}

echo ""
echo "++++++++++++ log.stdout"
cat log.stdout
echo "++++++++++++ log.stderr"
cat log.stderr
echo "++++++++++++"
```

Now run the script:

```
$ logout

eval date ${log}

++++++++++++ log.stdout
Sun Jul 23 15:56:01 CDT 2017
++++++++++++ log.stderr
++++++++++++

eval date xyz ${log}

++++++++++++ log.stdout
++++++++++++ log.stderr
date: invalid date `xyz'
++++++++++++
```

Comment: The use of `eval` is strongly discouraged. Especially with user-supplied strings. This is not a safe way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: My first post was a brief example of how `eval` can be used; OP could still use `eval` in his script since he's not actually letting the user supply any potentially nefarious commands; I've updated the post to provide an example that doesn't show running any user-supplied strings; happy now? :-)